# Warnings amount comparison between previous build and the current in Jenkins using SonarQube with MSBuild

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube

I am curious if it is possible to *prevent Jenkins from building an application if the amount of warnings is grater than in the previous build*. I was aiming to use SonarQube, because I have some set of rules already specified. I am aware of existence of [Warnings Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin), but SonarQube gives much more opportunities I suppose.
I was digging through documentation and I haven't found any markups about such possibility. Is there any way to set a sort of flag? Could you be that kind and maybe point me in the right direction? Maybe SonarQube does not support my need in this matter?
I would really appreciate any assistance.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language, you're putting the cart before the horse.

Specifically, for Java, C#, and C-Family languages you must build before you can analyze.

For other languages (JS, PHP, Python, ...) this would be theoretically possible, but:

You need to grab the current issue count before analysis & compare it with issue count after analysis. At this point, you've already updated the project in SonarQube. Why not just let the full pipeline run and decide based on the Quality Gate status whether or not the project is releasable.

If you're just looking at total issue count, you'll miss the case where I remove one old issue and add 1 new one.

And focusing on raw issue count ignores severity (e.g. Blocker vs Info), and type (Bug vs Code Smell).

Instead, you should be looking at issue-related metrics *on new code*. Incorporate those into your [Quality Gate](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Gates), and make decisions (post-build) based on your project's Quality Gate status.